# NumberFormatException при считывании чисел из файла

Tags: java, файлы, исключения

Есть текстовый файл, который содержит целые числа, каждое с новой строки:

*num.txt*

```
32
4
8
3
2
```

При выполнении следующего кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = reader1.readLine();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    while (reader.ready()) {
        buf = reader.readLine();                      
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(buf));
    }
}
```

Вылетает ошибка `NumberFormatException`.
При работе с консолью всё работает нормально.

Считывает он вроде то что нужно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = reader1.readLine();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    String buf = "";
    try {
        while (reader.ready()) {
            buf = reader.readLine();                      
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(buf));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Мы считали: " + buf);
    }
}
```

> Мы считали: 32

Где ошибка?

Comment: В stacktrace у `NumberFormatException` указывается строка, которая приводит к появлению исключения. Проанализируйте её, а также добавьте stacktrace в вопрос.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "32".  Не знаю как добавить это в вопрос

Comment: В нижней части вопроса, чуть ниже меток, есть кнопка "Править". Нажмите на неё и добавьте весь stacktrace в конец текста вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если метод `trim` не справляется с задачей (в частности, он удаляет только символы с кодами от `0` до `32` включительно и только из начала и конца строки), то справиться может `replaceAll`:

```
buf = buf.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Который удалит из строки все символы, не являющиеся цифрами.

Чтобы выяснить какие же символы содержатся в строке, можно воспользоваться таким методом:

```
private static void displayChars(String str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print((int)str.charAt(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

Если `System.out.println("Мы считали: " + buf);` заменить на `displayChars(buf);`, то должно стать понятно что же за символы "портят жизнь".

---

Таким символом может оказаться `65279` (то есть BOM), находящий в самом начале файла.

Comment: Спасибо! replaceAll() помог. Перевел строку в массив символов и вывел коды символов массива. Оказалось, что там присутствует символ 65279, "Символ этот не что иное, как BOM (Byte Order Mark) который находится в начале файла с кодировкой UTF-8, и возможно некоторых других юникодных кодировок. Используется для индикации порядка байтов. Ну, чтоб показать 16-битные или 32-разрядных числа используются"

Comment: @Денис на здоровье. Да, это был наиболее вероятный вариант. Однако в ответе я про него писать не стал, потому что у меня этот символ (уж не знаю по какой причине) виден в `Мы считали: 32` в виде точки без `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает, скорее всего, из-за того, что после числа идет пробел или какой-то другой подобный символ. Есть предложение: после считывания строки вызвать для неё метод `trim()`. Этот метод удаляет пробелы в начале и конце строки.

Тогда парсинг будет выглядеть так:

```
Integer.parseInt(buf.trim())
```

Comment: trim() не помог. При выводе в консоль buf выводится без пробелов и переносов